# How to check USB port and give device (memory, etc) information in linux using c++

Tags: c++, linux, usb

I need help to create program to check usb port in Linux using C++ to obtain device status ( `hid`,`uid`, etc.).

Comment: you better tag this question with 'linux' tag too

Answer (score 2):

Given that you mention C++ I am assuming this is a user space program, rather than a kernel driver. The [`libusb`](http://www.libusb.org/) project should serve your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**lsusb** - List usb buses and device details

This command shows the USB controllers and details about devices connected to them. By default brief information is printed. ***Use the verbose option "-v" to print detailed information about each usb port***

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

For more information [click](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/) here